# Garbled text with ean13isbn -- what gives?

Tags: xetex, pdftex

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ean13isbn}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\EANisbn[ISBN=978-80-7340-097-2]
\end{document}
```

Below is what I get with both `xelatex` and `pldflatex`. What's going on?

[image]

EDIT: Here's my log file, after running with `xelatex`:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.7.14)  15 JAN 2021 16:25
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**mwe.tex
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count163
\c@section=\count164
\c@subsection=\count165
\c@subsubsection=\count166
\c@paragraph=\count167
\c@subparagraph=\count168
\c@figure=\count169
\c@table=\count170
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ean13isbn/ean13isbn.sty
Package: ean13isbn 2008/06/20 EAN13 with ISBN
Package ean13isbn Info: $Id: ean13isbn.sty 208 2008-06-19 23:25:37Z zw $.

(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ean/ean13.tex
The EAN-13 barcodes macro. Copyright (C) Petr Olsak, 1995
\numlines=\count171
\nummodules=\count172
\numdigit=\count173
\evensum=\count174
\oddsum=\count175
\X=\dimen135
\bcorr=\dimen136
\workdimen=\dimen137
\barheight=\dimen138
)
\zw@isbnfsize=\dimen139
)
(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 225.

(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.
def
File: l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def 2020-06-29 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
\g__graphics_track_int=\count176
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count177
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count178
) (./mwe.aux)
\openout1 = `mwe.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 4
.

(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
EAN: 9 788073 400972
EANinternal: 011113123121312132112131141111111113232113211311213122122111
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+phv on input line 5
.

(/home/kristian/texlive2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd
File: ot1phv.fd 2020/03/25 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.
)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/phv/mc/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/phv/m/n' instead on input line 5.

[1

] (./mwe.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1560 strings out of 479277
 23295 string characters out of 5879017
 265953 words of memory out of 5000000
 19260 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 533902 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 33i,5n,37p,202b,210s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on mwe.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: Have you tried the examples in the manual? There is an option that influences the size.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I just tried the questioner's MWE and the examples in the manual (which are just some code-phrases but not full compilable MWEs!!!) and different size-options: With any attempt I get the same mess as the questioner.  The mess does have different sizes.

Comment: looks okay for me. Can you show your log-file?

Comment: @UlrichDiez that would explain the output, but I don't get this substituation.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I also tried on learnlatex.org, there it worked too, so it is not some local. You perhaps have some outdated files (your patch level is certainly older).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I edited the question and added my log file.

Comment: Try if it works with `\makeatletter
\input{ot1phv.fd}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{phv}{mc}{n}{
   <-> \Hv@@scale phvr7tn
}{}
\makeatother`  (your latex is older, in newer one it should not be needed).

Comment: With even older LaTeX (TeX Live 2019) it also works, so you should try _very_ new or not-so-new but not something in between :)

Comment: @Marijn: Yes, I remember using this with TeX Live 2019 without issue!

Comment: You're loading files from a 2019 TeX Live, but using the executable from TeX Live 2020. If you're updating files manually, don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by combination of recent changes in PSNFSS and NFSS2. The old version still works but can fail depending on your installation. It is fixed in version 2021-01-24 which was uploaded to CTAN a few hours ago and should be available in distributions within a few days.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, everyone!

What I ended up doing was downloading `ean13isbn.sty` file from CTAN. Upon compiling, I got this error:

```
LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 21.
```

Then I found the offending `mc` (the only one) and changed it to `c`. Now the barcode looks as it should:

[image]

I'm not sure that's the entirely proper way to approach these things, but it worked!

Comment: well the proper way is to contact the author so that they can correct the code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Done!